# Blank acoustic fingerprint when using Chromaprint

Tags: c++, audio, audio-fingerprinting

I am trying to differentiate between multiple wav files using acoustic fingerprinting. I am using Chromaprint from AcoustID. I am using 32 bit windows. I have downloaded the file fpcalc.exe and am trying to run it on multiple wav files. The problem is, it is generating blank FINGERPRINT for those wav files. 
I am running the command

```
fpcalc.exe -raw <FILENAME>.wav
```

The files are in wav format and the size of the files is 1 SEC. I am running the same command on bigger files, then the FINGERPRINT is working fine.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chromaprint library only works for larger files, I think the files should have at least 10 seconds to fingerprint.

Maybe you should look for alternatives like Python and Ruby who have libraries to fingerprint small audio files (if you search a bit).

---

**You can use the gem that I made for wav files:**

https://rubygems.org/gems/audio-fingerprint

Comment: Thanks :) . Lukas explained it to me in this post..
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/acoustid/Wo5zisCxU8Y

Comment: @Abhishek I'm looking for an answer too, if you find one that fits our needs to fingerprint small files, send me an email and let's work together.

Comment: @Rafel Actually for that small files.. I used md5hash or similar hashing algo to compare two files. I had only requirement that two small audio files should be same. I did not look it up any further on fingerprinting.

Comment: @Abhishek That's a smart answer for your problem. My problem is a little bit more complex, I'm trying to make my computer execute commands with my voice. I already have a prototype using one of the Google's services with voice recognition. But the problem is that I'm afraid to depend on Google. I'm pretty sure they'll add limits and billing in the future, so I kinda need to learn fingerprint and build my own API.

Comment: Thats cool. You can start a project on gitHub and I will be happy to contribute.

Comment: Did anything come of this @Abhishek or Rafael?

Comment: That was a long time ago @TomDunning I can't recall what happened to this. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, I was just hoping there was a chunk of code sat in a repo somewhere.